# Set index of a list by using another list

Tags: python, list, pandas

Afternoon,

I have a list which i currently set the index by changing the code manually.

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['Stock', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3'], append=True)
```

How would i go about automating this so that i am able to set the index of a list by using another list, for instance:

```
k = ['Stock', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3]
```

thanks

Comment: `df1 = df1.set_index(k, append=True)` ?

Comment: Thanks was being dense and missed the underscore,

Answer (score 1):

When you create a variable in python (and many programming languages), you are simply creating a *pointer* to the actual data sitting in memory. It makes it easier to reference and remember `k` as a human than the memory address where `['Stock', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3']` is.

So like Erica mentioned in her comment, when you just put `k` in place of the list, it populates `k` with the actual data, `['Stock', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3']`.

This way you can keep your list outside of the `set_index` method and just reference the list with the variable `k`:

```
k = ['Stock', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3']
df1 = df1.set_index(k, append=True)
```

The benefit of doing it this way is you can now much more easily change `k`, and *everywhere k is used* gets updated, since they're all just pointing to the same place in memory and you just changed the data at that memory.

```
k = ['Stock', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3']
df1 = df1.set_index(k, append=True)
...
k.append('custom_attribute')  # df1.set_index is updated now.
```